# Devolver / return objeto en un método

Tags: java

A la hora de retornar un objeto dentro de un método me devuelve esta información codificada y no se a que se debe.

```
/**
 * Paquete del proyecto
 */
package UF2;


class Objeto {
    /**
     * numero --> variable que guarda un número
     */
    int numero;
    /**
     * numero2 --> variable que guarda un número
     */
    int numero2;

}


public class Prueba_clases {

    /**
     * Array que contiene números
     */
    int numeros [] = new int [] {2,2,1,1,3};

    /**
     * 
     * @return la suma de los dos números
     */
    Objeto SumarNumeros(){

        Objeto ob = new Objeto ();

        ob.numero=0;
        ob.numero2=0;

        for (int i = 0; i < numeros.length; i++) {
            if (numeros[i] == 1) {
                ob.numero++;
            } else if (numeros[i] == 3) {
                ob.numero2++;
            }

        }

        ob.numero=ob.numero+ob.numero2; // tiene que sumar 2+1=3


        return ob;

    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Prueba_clases prog = new Prueba_clases();

        System.out.println(prog.SumarNumeros());
    }

}
```

> Y me devuelve esto --> UF2.Objeto@15db9742

Comment: Implementa el método `toString()` de `Objeto`

Comment: No imprimas el objeto imprime la propiedad que deseas del objeto, en este caso la suma:  System.out.println(prog.SumarNumeros().numero); para obtener como resultado 3.

Answer (score 6):

Es completamente normal. En Java existe un método llamado `toString` que pertenece a la clase `Object`, clase que es padre de todas las clases. Este método, por defecto, **retorna el nombre de la clase más su hashcode**:

> nombredelaclase@hashcode

Esto no aplica a tipos primitivos obviamente. Lo que debes hacer es **sobreescribir** ese método para retornar lo que desees:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
  return numero;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Quiero aportar algunos ejemplos, sólo para reforzar la respuesta de @GustavoGarcia.

[La Clase `Object`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString()) de Java posee un método llamado `toString()`, el cual tiene la siguiente representación:

```
public String toString()
```

Y es definido en la documentación de la siguiente manera (las negritas son mías):

> Devuelve **una representación** de cadena del objeto. En general, el
>   método `toString` devuelve una cadena que **"representa textualmente"
>   este objeto**. El resultado debe ser una representación concisa pero
>   informativa que sea **fácil de leer para una persona**. **Se recomienda que
>   todas las subclases sobre-escriban (anulen) este método**.
>
> El método `toString` para la clase `Object` devuelve una cadena que
>   consta del nombre de la clase de la que el objeto es una instancia, el
>   carácter '`@`' y la representación hexadecimal sin signo del código
>   hash del objeto. En otras palabras, este método devuelve una cadena
>   igual al valor de:
>
> ```
>  getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())
> ```

De ahí se deduce que **toda clase que no sobre-escriba el método `toString()` devolverá una cadena ilegible para los humanos**.

---

### ¿Cómo se sobre-escribe?

Dotando a la clase de un método `toString()` creado por uno mismo, que devuelva los datos en la forma en que nos interesen.

He aquí un ejemplo de los dos casos:

<kbd>[**VER DEMO**](http://rextester.com/UVOIIT69749)</kbd>

```
class Rextester
{  
    public static void main(String args[])
    {

       Person p1=new Person(1,"Pedro","Galilela");  
       Person p2=new Person(2,"Santiago","Betsaida");  
       Person p3=new Person(3,"Juan","Patmos");  

        //El compilador usará .toString()
       System.out.println("Con el toString() por defecto\n"); 
       System.out.println(p1); 
       System.out.println(p2); 
       System.out.println(p3); 

       PersonWithToString pw1=new PersonWithToString(1,"Pedro","Galilela");  
       PersonWithToString pw2=new PersonWithToString(2,"Santiago","Betsaida");  
       PersonWithToString pw3=new PersonWithToString(3,"Juan","Patmos");  

        //El compilador usará .toString() sobre-escrito
       System.out.println("\n\nCon el toString() sobre-escrito\n"); 
       System.out.println(pw1); 
       System.out.println(pw2); 
       System.out.println(pw3);        


    }
}



    class Person
    {  
         int personId;  
         String personName;  
         String personCity;  

         Person(int personId, String personName, String personCity)
         {  
             this.personId=personId;  
             this.personName=personName;  
             this.personCity=personCity;  
         }  


     }  


    class PersonWithToString
    {  
         int personId;  
         String personName;  
         String personCity;  

         PersonWithToString(int personId, String personName, String personCity)
         {  
             this.personId=personId;  
             this.personName=personName;  
             this.personCity=personCity;  
         }  

        //Se sobre-escribe el método toString() por defecto de la clase
        public String toString()
        {  
          return personId+" "+personName+" "+personCity;
         }  


     }
```

**Resultado:**

```
Con el toString() por defecto

Person@15db9742
Person@6d06d69c
Person@7852e922


Con el toString() sobre-escrito

1 Pedro Galilela
2 Santiago Betsaida
3 Juan Patmos
```

Answer (score 0):

> A la hora de retornar un objeto dentro de un método me devuelve esta
>   información codificada y no se a que se debe.

La respuesta es que estas imprimiendo el objeto y no sus propiedades, si revisas tu método `SumarNumeros()`, lo que retorna es un objeto:

```
   Objeto SumarNumeros(){
        Objeto ob = new Objeto ();
        ob.numero=0;
        ob.numero2=0;
        for (int i = 0; i < numeros.length; i++) {
            if (numeros[i] == 1) {
                ob.numero++;
            } else if (numeros[i] == 3) {
                ob.numero2++;
            }
        }
        ob.numero=ob.numero+ob.numero2; // tiene que sumar 2+1=3
        return ob;
    }
```

Si lo imprimes :

```
 System.out.println(prog.SumarNumeros());
```

obtendras una representación del objeto

```
UF2.Objeto@15db9742
```

**Lo que nos interesa son las propiedades que se modificaron al realizar operaciones dentro del objeto que son `numero` y `numero2`, para obtener esta información imprime únicamente sus propiedades**:

```
 System.out.println(prog.SumarNumeros().numero);
 System.out.println(prog.SumarNumeros().numero2);
```

tendrás como resultado:

```
3
1
```

---

Puedes incluso realizar un método que entregue la suma de los números, este método retornaría un valor entero:

```
 private int SumarNumeros(){
        Objeto ob = new Objeto ();
        ob.numero=0;
        ob.numero2=0;
        for (int i = 0; i < numeros.length; i++) {
            if (numeros[i] == 1) {
                ob.numero++;
            } else if (numeros[i] == 3) {
                ob.numero2++;
            }
        }        
        return ob.numero+ob.numero2; // tiene que sumar 2+1=3
    }
```

De esta forma podrías imprimir:

```
System.out.println(prog.SumarNumeros());
```

y obtener como resultado:

```
3
```

Answer (score 0):

Tras la magnífica explicación de `@Gustavo García`, creo que solo falta mencionar cómo aplicarlo:

```
class Objeto {
    /**
     * numero --> variable que guarda un número
     */
    int numero;
    /**
     * numero2 --> variable que guarda un número
     */
    int numero2;

    /**
     * He aquí la magia
     */
    @Override
    public string toString(){
        return (numero + numero2).toString();
    }
}
```

y lo mandas imprimir con

```
System.out.println(prog.SumarNumeros().toString());
```