# ¿Crear ArrayList, agregar varios datos al mismo array desde otras clases e imprimirlos?

Tags: java, clase, lista

Finalmente y con ayuda de mi profesor pude lograrlo, adjunto el código fuente.

```
package prueba2;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Concesionario {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Lista list = new Lista();
    Socio socio = new Socio();
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);     
    int n = 0;
    System.out.println("Ingrese su Nombre");            
    String nombre = scan.nextLine();
    socio.setNombre(nombre);
    list.setSocios(socio.getNombre());
    String nombreList = list.getSocios();
    System.out.println(nombreList);
    list.array(nombre);
    }
}

public class Lista extends CompraVenta {
    static private Lista sc;
    private String socios;
    ArrayList<String> lista = new ArrayList();

public String getSocios() {
    return socios;
}

public void setSocios(String socios) {
    this.socios = socios;
}

public void array(String nombre) {
    lista.add(nombre);
    System.out.println(lista);
    }
}

public class CompraVenta {
    private Lista sc;

static public void Compra() {   
    Compra();                                           
    }
}
```

Comment: Depende de la visibilidad de la lista en la clase. Si la lista es pública, basta con acceder directamente a ella desde la instancia de la clase: `A a = new A(); a.nombres.add("Christofer");`. Si la lista es privada, debes usar un método **público** para acceder a ella (getter) o que reciba el nombre e internamente lo agregue a la lista.

Comment: Hola, he agregado la list de la que estoy hablando, intenté la manera que me has dicho pero sigue marcando error.

Comment: Desde otra clase: `instancia.getSocios().add("Christofer");`. Añade el modificador `private` a `socios`.

Comment: No hay error, al parecer estás imprimiendo un objeto. En Java todo objeto hereda de la clase Object, la cual tiene un método `toString`, el cual devuelve por defecto el nombre de la clase más su hashcode; este método es el que se ejecuta al imprimir un objeto. Por ende, si quieres que al imprimir un objeto se muestre algo diferente, deberas **sobreescribir** el método `toString`.

Comment: Para más detalle ver [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/79615/devolver-return-objeto-en-un-método/79623#79623).

Comment: Si lo que quieres es mostrar el contenido de la lista debes **iterarla**: `for(String socio : lista.getSocios()) { System.out.println(socio); }`.

Comment: funcionó! muchas gracias!

Comment: Hola, la lista almacena la variable que ingreso y la imprime correctamente, pero no puedo agregar nuevos nombres, ya que se reemplazan entre sí, ¿cómo podría corregir ésto?

Comment: No debe pasar eso, ya que el método `add` agrega cualquier cantidad de elementos, solo limitado por memoria. La única razón por la que sucede esto es porque quizás instancias varias veces a `Lista`. PD: No uses el mismo nombre de la clase para un método, ya que este nombre está reservado para el constructor de la clase, el cual no debe retornar nada.

Comment: @ÇhristoferParra para agregar nuevos nombres, simplemente agregalos al list : sc.getSocios().add("Elenasys"); ve mi respuesta. Para imprimirlos agregué un método-.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para imprimir el List puedes usar simplemente

```
System.out.println(sc.getSocios());
```

pero esto imprimiría seguramente

```
[Christofer]
```

---

Para imprimir uno o varios elementos contenidos en el List puedes usar un método :

```
private static void imprimeList(List<String> array){        
     for (String elemento: array) {
        System.out.println(elemento);
    }
}
```

Este método puedes agregarlo a tu clase e imprimir el contenido de los elementos del list `getSocios()` que tiene visibilidad `public`

```
public class CompraVenta {

    private static void imprimeList(List<String> array){        
         for (String elemento: array) {
            System.out.println(elemento);
        }
    }

public void CompraVenta() {
    Lista sc = new Lista();
    sc.getSocios().add("Christofer");
    sc.getSocios().add("Elenasys");
    sc.getSocios().add("Ioana");
    sc.getSocios().add("Constantin");

    //System.out.println("sc");

    imprimeList(sc.getSocios());

   }
}
```

Esto imprimiría como resultado:

```
Christofer
Elenasys
Ioana
Constantin
```

---

**Actualización**:

Define una variable de clase

```
private Lista sc;
```

Inicializala dentro de tu metodo main() :

```
sc = new Lista();
```

En tu mètodo Compra(), unicamente agrega los elementos.

```
public void Compra() {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
 //   Lista sc = new Lista();
    System.out.println("Ingrese su Nombre");
    String nombre = scan.nextLine();
    sc.getSocios().add(nombre);
    imprimeList(soc.getSocios());
   }
}
```

El problema es en realidad que estas creando una nueva instancia de lista cada vez que llamas el metodo Compra(), por lo tanto solo contiene un elemento siempre.

Comment: Seguí tus instrucciones (como se ve en el código) pero no imprime todos los valores que agrego, solo el ultimo, ¿qué está mal?

Comment: Sigo intentando y buscando, pero no encuentro la solución :c

Comment: Hola veo que tu problema en realidad es que imprimer ùnicamente el ùltimo valor insertado. Permiteme un momento y realizo una actualización.

Comment: Agregue una actualización, te sugiero agregues tu código para decirte especificamente como corregir.

Comment: Hola, actualicé y agregué mi código completo para corrección.

Answer (score 1):

Buenos días,

ArrayList tiene su propia implementación de toString(). Simplemente tienes que cambiar la línea

```
 System.out.println("sc");
```

por:

```
System.out.println(sc.getSocios());
```

Lo he probado y ya te imprime [Christofer].

Comment: Saludos, efectivamente tu respuesta es correcta, muchas gracias, sin embargo ahora no puedo agregar nuevos nombres, ya que se reemplazan entre sí y solo se almacena e imprime el último nombre ingresado, ¿cómo podría corregir ésta situación?

Comment: El código fuente que has puesto arriba en la pregunta, ¿te compila? ¿Está en el mismo fichero?. Te lo digo porque a primera vista veo dos fallos:
1) `sc = new Lista();  // Me aparece error.`
2) Tienes dos clases públicas dentro del fichero, solo puede existir una y además coincidir con el "nombre del fichero".java.

El fallo 1) se solucionaría añadiendo Lista:

`Lista sc = new Lista();  // Me aparece error.`

El segundo haciendo solo una clase pública o ninguna.

Comment: Compilaba y podía agregar datos, el problema era que solo guardaba el último dato ingresado, según @Jorgesys era por que creaba una nueva instancia cada vez que ejecutaba el método, seguí sus indicaciones para corregir ese problema pero ahora no me compila, de seguro no lo hice como debía o me falta algo.

Answer (score 1):

Al imprimir una Lista ya sea `ArrayList` o cualquiera tienes que indicarle la posición que quieres mostrar

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> lista = new ArrayList();
        lista.add("Paco");
        lista.add("Luis");
        lista.add("Felipe");

        for(int i=0;i<lista.size();i++){
            System.out.println(lista.get(i));
        }
    }
```

Esto mostraría

> Paco
>
> Luis
>
> Felipe

Esto se puede hacer también con `Iterator` y `while` pero creo que con el `for` es más simple de ver y si la lista es de otros Objetos que no sea `String` , lo normal es que esa Objeto disponga de un método `toString()` para poder mostrar los atributos del objeto haríamos.

```
System.out.println(lista.get(i).toString());
```